# How to "mask" certain text in a PDF document

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF document, and I want to mask certain text blocks. The reason why I want to do this, is because I don't want this text to be indexed, nor I want this information to be easily accessible by selecting and copying this text block.

What should be the right way to do this?
I guess turning the text to raster would be bad idea, and I don't know if there is some tool that can make only cartain text parts with special privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a program that can convert a font into a series of shapes.

Illustrator may have the functionality you want: see [here](http://www.graphic-design-employment.com/adobe-illustrator-how-to-convert.html) and [here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/convert-text-to-path-32587.html).

Comment: Thanks, that seems like right way to me too, now. I somehow didn't thought about it.